# Ionic 3 audio handling when ovelapped

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

i have a situation where multiple buttons i have on page and very button has a audio when clicked. when i click on a button it audio plays and while playing when i click on other button audio gets overlapped. i need to stop first audio when other button is clicked.

here is the code

```
<div class= "sections" style="width: 18%;" (tap)="wajid1()"  (press) = "wajidlong1()">
      <div class = "sections" id = "sec1b" >
       ﻊَ  
      </div><!--
      --><div class = "sections" id = "sec2b" >
         ﻤَ  
      </div><!--
      --><div class = "sections" id = "sec3b" >
           ﺟَ  
      </div>

    </div>
```

this is my .ts code

```
wajid1()
   {
   document.getElementById("sec1b").style.color = "red";
   document.getElementById("sec2b").style.color = "red";
   document.getElementById("sec3b").style.color = "red"
   var bleep = new Audio();
   bleep.src = './assets/sounds/p10_2.mp3';
   bleep.play();
   bleep.onended = function() {
   document.getElementById("sec1b").style.color = "black";
   document.getElementById("sec2b").style.color = "black";
   document.getElementById("sec3b").style.color = "black";
  }

 }
```

help me to achieve this thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code snippet. Declare **Audio() at global** and use **pause()** method and **currentTime** for Audio object

```
export class HomePage {
    bleep = new Audio();
    wajid1()
    {
        this.bleep.pause();
        this.bleep.currentTime = 0;
        document.getElementById("sec1b").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("sec2b").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("sec3b").style.color = "red"

        this.bleep.src = './assets/sounds/p10_2.mp3';
        this.bleep.play();
        this.bleep.onended = function() {
            document.getElementById("sec1b").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("sec2b").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("sec3b").style.color = "black";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you.!

Comment: can you help me with firebase and ionic 3 ? i have to download a audio in phone and play it offline